# observer onChanged() incoming List<MovieRoom> is null

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My app fetches movies JSON data via AsyncTask (in updateMovies() method) and writes the data to the Android Room database.  The app also has a ViewModel which will get all the entries from the db.  However, when observer onChanged() is triggered, the incoming value set is null.

I suspect that the AsyncTask hasn't written the data to the Room DB yet, so that when onChanged() is called, there are no incoming values.

Is there any way I can ensure that the data is written to Room DB BEFORE I execute any of the ViewModel/observer related calls?

See code below:

````
        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,
                new Factory(this.getApplication()))
                .get(MainViewModel.class);

        mViewModel.movies.observe(this, new Observer<List<MovieRoom>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MovieRoom> movieEntries) {
                //Log.d(TAG, "Receiving database update from LiveData");
                // mMovieAdapter.mMovies = 0
                mMovieAdapter.clear();
                // movieEntries = 0
                // mMovieAdapter mMovies = 0
                mMovieAdapter.setList(movieEntries);
                mMovieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });```


```public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    public LiveData<List<MovieRoom>> movies;
    private AppDatabase database;
    public MutableLiveData<List<MovieRoom>> mutableMovies = new MutableLiveData<List<MovieRoom>>();


    /*
        Use constructor to initialize all data that UI needs to populate
     */
    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        database = AppDatabase.getInstance(application);
      mutableMovies.setValue((List<MovieRoom>)database.movieDao().getAllMovies().getValue());
        movies = mutableMovies;
    }



    public LiveData<List<MovieRoom>> getAllMovies() {
        mutableMovies.setValue((List<MovieRoom>) database.movieDao().getAllMovies().getValue());
        return mutableMovies;
    }
````

Comment: Please add your code it's hard to understand

Comment: ok just added code